# Как повернуть фон не трогая остальные элементы?

Tags: css3, html5

```
body {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(27deg, #1100ff 0%, #aa55f3 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(27deg, #1100ff 0%, #aa55f3 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(27deg, #1100ff 0%, #aa55f3 100%);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Суть такова, что надо повернуть фон под 45 не трогая остальные элементы. При использовании transform поворачивает всю страницу, а нужно только фон

Comment: у вас же угол в deg указан в градиенте ...его поверните

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/oRgBXq вот посмотрите - как deg влияет на угол градиента

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если фон чисто градиентный, то проще всего изменить направление/угол, как вам советовали в комментариях.

Если у вас что-то посложнее, например, изображение, то можно сделать дополнительный элемент или псевдоэлемент с фоновым изображением и повернуть его. Например, так:

```
body:before {
content: "";
position: fixed;
background-image: url('%image_url%');
width: 200vw;
height: 200vh;
z-index: -1;
transform: translatex(-50%) translatey(-50%) rotate(45deg);
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
}
```